# get string between start and close tag using Regular expression c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want pass out tag name and output will start tag and end tag between text using c#

```
var  mystring="{start}
 {leftimg}<http://frontier-gateway.net/postoffice/images/icons/icon_alert.png>{/leftimg} 
{topimg}<http://frontier-gateway.net/postoffice/images/sent/img_header.png>{/topimg}
{usrname}<Administrator>{/usrname} 
{msg}<This is a test broadcast message.>{/msg}
 {action}<mysite.com/action.php>{/action} 
{end}" 


var a=Regex.Match(mystring, @"{leftimg}\s*(.+?)\s*{/leftimg}").Groups[0].Value;
```

now i will get only text in whenever start and end tag.

Current Output:

```
{leftimg}http://frontier-gateway.net/postoffice/images/icons/icon_alert.png{/leftimg}
```

I want this type output (remove start and end tag in string):

http://frontier-gateway.net/postoffice/images/icons/icon_alert.png

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the first item of the `GroupCollection` class returns the full match. To access what's in the first capturing group, you need to use `.Groups[1]` instead of `.Groups[0]`.

**From the [`GroupCollection` class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection):**

> For each match, the GroupCollection contains three Group objects.
>   **The first object contains the string that matches the entire regular expression**. The second object, which represents the first captured
>   group, contains the product name. The third object, which represents
>   the second captured group, contains the trademark or registered
>   trademark symbol.

<strike>One more thing, you need to escape the forward slash in the "end tag", that is, use `{\/leftimg}` instead of `{/leftimg}`</strike>. I was wrong about that. Forward slash characters don't have to be escaped in .NET regexes.

**The following should work as you expect:**

```
var imgURL = Regex.Match(mystring, @"{leftimg}<\s*(.+?)\s*>{/leftimg}").Groups[1].Value;
```